# Is there a better way to do a 4 bits circular shifting?

Tags: .net, bit-manipulation

is this the *optimal* way of doing a 4 bits circular shifting?

```
    n << 1 ^ 0x10 | n >> 3
```

I was only testing with number that was actually "*working*"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually try this?  It is non-optimal, it generates garbage results.  This ought to work better:

```
    static int RollLeft4Bits(int n) {
        return ((n << 1) & 15) | ((n >> 3) & 1);
    }
```

Comment: wow, I just retested my code with something else than 12 and 9 for n and your right, my code is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good to me. But if you are really that concerned about optimisation, then try compiling this and any alternatives you have, and then using ildasm or [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to look at the IL generated to see for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could also generate a lookup table of every possible value and the shifted result.  Then just use the input as an index into the lookup table to get the desired result